# android file isn't available inside tools folder

Tags: android, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to create an Android project from command line. To do this, I am following tutorials from [http://developer.android.com/](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project.html#CommandLine). In the tutorial, I am told to execute the following command to see the list of all installed platforms on my system,

```
tools/android list targets
```

So I nevigated to the tools folder, inside my Android SDK installation, and tried to execute the `android` file, but it gives me the following error `android: command not found`. But if I list all files in that directory I see that the **android** file exists. This looks bizarre to me.

What am I doing wrong?

I am attaching a screenshot for clarification,
[image]

Comment: Use `./android` syntax or add this directory to `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. But why I need to add `./` before a file that's already executable?

Comment: @OleksiiKropachov Can you please post your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `./android` syntax or add this directory to `PATH` environment variable.